# Type-safe usage of implementations of generic interface

Tags: typescript

I have a generic interface that I have a number of concrete implementations of.

Each implementation handles its own structure of data, and I have a factory function of sorts, that using some input will determine which concrete class to return to the main flow of code to use.

I'm struggling to correctly add typings to the code in such a way that it understands it may be given class One or Two at runtime, however whichever it is given it will continue to use the same instance for the remainder of the code and so should be able to guarantee type safety.

I've tried a couple of different options but neither are working as I'm intending. In each case I can understand why they aren't working, but can't figure out what I should be doing instead.

**Using Union Types**

This throws a TS error at the useData call, which is understandable given I've told the main function to expect a union of the two types and the concrete class expects a narrower version of that union.

```js
interface GenericService<Data extends {}> {
  getData(): Data;
  useData(data: Data): Data;
}

class ConcreteOne implements GenericService<{ foo: string }> {
  getData() {
    return { foo: 'bar' };
  }

  useData(data: { foo: string }): { foo: string } {
    return data;
  }
}

class ConcreteTwo implements GenericService<{ foo: number }> {
  getData() {
    return { foo: 1 };
  }

  useData(data: { foo: number }): { foo: number } {
    return data;
  }
}

function getConcrete(number: 1 | 2): ConcreteOne | ConcreteTwo {
  if(number === 1) {
    return new ConcreteOne();
  }
  if(number === 2) {
    return new ConcreteTwo();
  }
  throw new Error();
}

function mainFunction(number: 1 | 2) {
  const concrete = getConcrete(number);
  const data = concrete.getData();
  concrete.useData(data); // TS Error: type string is not assignable to type number
}
```

**Using Generics**

Again, understandable that this doesn't throw an error given I've told the main function that any concrete class returned from `getConcrete` accepts a data type of `{}`.

```js
function getConcrete(number: 1 | 2): GenericService<{}> {
  if(number === 1) {
    return new ConcreteOne();
  }
  if(number === 2) {
    return new ConcreteTwo();
  }
  throw new Error();
}

function mainFunction(number: 1 | 2) {
  const concrete1 = getConcrete(1);
  const concrete2 = getConcrete(2);
  const data = concrete1.getData();
  concrete2.useData(data); // I want this to throw a type error along the lines of "concrete2 may be a different sub-type of GenericService to concrete1"
}
```

In plain terms I'm looking for a way to declare:

- You will get a class from the factory that conforms to an interface method-wise, and because of generics you know that return types/arguments of that class's methods match up.
- So long as the returned value from the call to the first method of the class is what is passed to the call to the second method, we're good.
- However if the returned value is passed to a different implementation of the interface, we can't be sure that we're good.

Is there a way I can achieve what I'm trying to?

Comment: One run-time solution is that `ConcreteTwo` class should check in its implementation of `useData` method what type of data it receives and throw an exception if the data originates from an unexpected source.

Comment: This has got [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) written all over it, and the recommended approach is described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  If I apply that to your code I get [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbBY8m); does that meet your needs?  If so, I can write it up as an answer.  If not, what am I missing?